# Store New and Old object into longblob - Trigger Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

In my trigger, I want to store the new and old objects into a longblob field of a log table.

I guess i have to serialize or cast these objects...but how ?

I haven't find any tips or helps on internet...

Thanks!

Comment: Something missing, what objects?

Comment: for example, I want to do that : 
`
CREATE TRIGGER `mytable_au` AFTER UPDATE ON `mytable` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `triggers_data` (`old` ,`new`) VALUES (old,new);
END
`

But this doesn't work, I have to replace "VALUES (old,new)" with something like VALUES (serialize(old),serialize(new))

Comment: Well you could build a fixed format string, or a bit of xml. Old and new are just copies of the record though, they are not objects. Oh and you need to think about if you want to log data from other tables, and what to do if the table structure changes. Are you sure you want to take the lid off this tin of worms.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Yes, a have to be vigilant about the structures changes... but I have no choice.
The records old and new will be temporary stored in my log table, end readen by a php script wich launch some commands.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the one table you are auditing then you could skip 'serialisation' altogether. Just add two records to audit with common key. You could do inserts and deletes as well then, as well.

Seeing as there's no easy way to tell mysql about the object, serialisation is going to be a fixed format text string, xml, may be a JSON hash or some such.

If you are going to audit from multiple tables an other column for a type, is required. Better still it allows you to version the type and coping with any potential breaking structural change.

I'be concerned with the overhead from triggers, if changes to the data are only sourced from one application, I'd seriously look at doing the auditing in the application itself, in which case you might find you can do more processing at audit time and get more benefits and options.